# Rewrite of block and helper for checkout getCheckoutUrl() not working

Tags: checkout, configuration, onepage-checkout, overrides, geturl

I'm trying to rewrite the getCheckoutUrl() functions in

> Mage/Checkout/Blocks/Onepage/Link.php

and

> Mage/Checkout/Helper/Url.php

but the rewrites don't seem to work.

My config.xml file contains the following:

```
...
<global>
    ...
    <blocks>
        <stores>
            <class>Zzyzzx_Stores_Block</class>
        </stores>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_link>Zzyzzx_Stores_Block_Link</onepage_link>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <stores>
            <class>Zzyzzx_Stores_Helper</class>
        </stores>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <url>Zzyzzx_Stores_Helper_Url</url>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </helpers>
    ...
</global>
...
```

Everything else defined in the ocnfig seems to be working fine, only the rewrites don't seem to.

the block rewrite refers to my file

> .../app/code/community/Zzyzzx/Stores/Block/Link.php

which contains:

```
class Zzyzzx_Stores_Block_Link extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Link
{
    function getCheckoutUrl()
    {
        //my changes
    }
}
```

the helpers rewrite refers to

> .../app/code/community/Zzyzzx/Stores/Helper/Url.php

which contains:

```
class Zzyzzx_Stores_Helper_Url extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url
{

    function getCheckoutUrl()
    {
        //my changes
    }

}
```

with the helper, I am able to directly access the function with `Mage::helper("stores/url")->getCheckoutUrl();` but the rewrite doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?  How do I get my rewrites working?

Comment: the code looks ok to me. Check if your `config.xml` is picked up. modify it so it will have an error (unclosed tag for example) and see if you get an error in the page. Also a common mistake can be in the declaration file `app/etc/modules/Zzyzzx_Store.xml`. Make sure you have `<codePool>community</codePool>` and not `<codepool>` as tag or `local` as value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: Please verify that your extension's config is being merged.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the long article about debugging](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Make sure your module.xml is loaded, by activating dev mode and then breaking the XML, so you see a simplexml_error, if this is the case break the config.xml to get the same error.

If these two files are loaded, make sure, that the two classes are used, xdebug is your friend `get_class` is the alternative.

If this all works, check the method names.